# Failed to startup WiredTiger under any compatibility version. 2020-04-13T20:51:43.938+0400 F STORAGE [initandlisten] Reason: 13: Permission denied

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We are using MongoDB with ArcGIS monitor when we restart ArcGIS service the connection to MongoDB failed.

Checking MongoDB logs we found below error:

2020-04-13T20:51:43.938+0400 W STORAGE [initandlisten] Failed to startup WiredTiger under any compatibility version.

2020-04-13T20:51:43.938+0400 F STORAGE [initandlisten] Reason: 13: Permission denied.

Trying to grant permission on file wiredTiger.lock but we couldn't with error:" You don't have permission to view or edit this object's permission setting" and the owner of the file is unknown. also, deleting the file is failed.

The account is administrator on the machine and has access to all other files the issue is only on this file.

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to figure out how you got into this state which I can't help with.

But you may be able to get rid of the file by taking ownership of it using a process like [this](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/).